# pivot table sorting by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have a pivot table and , with VBA code, I would like the values in the 'Country' field to be in the exact order I specified:
(blank), Czech Republic, Finland, Denmark, Norway, Spain, Greece, Brazil, Argentina

This is what I have:
[initial pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRcKY.png)

(I know Norway isn't in my table, but if it does show up, it should be in the right place after running the code)

I was trying to achieve my goal using the code below but with no luck.

```
Sub my_pivot()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Sheet4").PivotTables("PivotTable2")

Application.AddCustomList Array("(blank)", "Czech Republic", "Finland", "Denmark", "Spain", "Greece", "Brazil", "Argentina")

PvtTbl.SortUsingCustomLists = True

PvtTbl.PivotFields("Country").DataRange.Sort Order1:=xlAscending, Type:=xlSortLabels

End Sub
```

When I run it and then I sort the column manually (A to Z), I get this:
[Second pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbjdM.png)

It seems to be fine except "(blank)" which is not at the beginning. I am confused. Do you have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Grab the (blank) row first and then  union the rest of the range:  https://wellsr.com/vba/2019/excel/use-vba-union-to-combine-ranges/#:~:text=The%20VBA%20Union%20method%20in,subset%20of%20a%20larger%20range.

Comment: Blanks can be set at the top with adding one more line at the end `PvtTbl.PivotFields("Country").PivotItems("(blank)").Position = 1`